# Typescript Generics and not assignable error

Tags: typescript

I seem to have a understanding problem of how typescript types works. I have the following situation. I have a class which provides a function which can be overriden:

```js
    /**
     * The current log method. Can be overridden to redirect output.
     */
    log: (...args: any[]) => void;
```

I have the following type

```js
type AzureTransport = {
  (...args: any[]): void
}
```

No I have a kind of facade which looks like:

```js
export interface DataChampLogger {
  info(...args: any[]): void
  error(...args: any[]): void
  warn(...args: any[]): void
  verbose(...args: any[]): void
  setLogLevel(level: DataChampLogLevel): void
  setTransport<T>(transport: T): void

// implementation
class .... {
 setTransport<AzureTransport>(transport: AzureTransport): void {
    AzureLogger.log = transport
  }
}
}
```

this does not work, I get the following error `Type 'AzureTransport' is not assignable to type '(...args: any[]) => void'.ts(2322)`

when I refactor the code to:

```js
export interface DataChampLogger {
  info(...args: any[]): void
  error(...args: any[]): void
  warn(...args: any[]): void
  verbose(...args: any[]): void
  setLogLevel(level: DataChampLogLevel): void
  setTransport(transport: unknown): void

// implementation
class .... {
 setTransport(transport: AzureTransport): void {
    AzureLogger.log = transport
  }
}
}
```

everything works fine, but it is not really clear to why I get an error in the first version of the implementation.

[edit] [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-4DELRpbJv1Bi0sfWhu4PJ7mPHmPp2uzkBhUbgoiZTXxgF1SThQOCgMA8lXMtwebx95pzBDPOAAYkTxkuA7nUEXBMX3V3PUX-KdUHQ5Bg0EOLF8GM1Isux7K11LS0RyL9K9mw9ClCwNHoTCZTdL2vbYxgzGMmxeepCRjbo4DoTY4EiFx0F4SVzzgCBkgpLpqRcCJRnQBh4BOL5iwKJFyC8EcUQAAydCIoCgWi4FQrBFCIoJcmHWUqHlGRDGVJl93Vaw+x5OARNo6SACsqCETtKGAMAYBEo94FXOZQhYLACinSYZ3ADdP0OdQwgZEAHHAl9Gk0qA-RWL0AV+ctKxDMN6xCKMF1gl8liPD0EwIVzU3TXcljkJ9XgwxN7FZAKeSk6SRI1LU1FI707Dw+wixzVlj1-NRE24FLeBcBBNCYUF80kN040LMifkgpYD2bGNHNy2AdgHJyBiODLnPXAtep+Dy4R8vzjKHIL8BLAaBkXJsFlxIA)

Thanks for your time and help

Regards
Mathias

Comment: Please provide reproducible example with all imports. You can test your example in ts playground. This syntax `class .... {` is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Typescript cannot know that the `AzureTransport` type that you use in the class will be assignable to `T`, since `T` could be something else.

You can add a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) like that:

```
export interface DataChampLogger {
  setTransport<T extends AzureTransport>(transport: T): void; // "T extends AzureTransport" is the constraint
}

class MyClass implements DataChampLogger {
  setTransport(transport: AzureTransport): void {
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can move the generic to the interface itself, like that:

```
export interface DataChampLogger<T> // generic is here  {
  setTransport(transport: T): void;
}

class MyClass implements DataChampLogger<AzureTransport> {
  setTransport(transport: AzureTransport): void { // no complaints since T is AzureTransport
  }
}
```

---

On a side note, this

```
type AzureTransport = {
  (...args: any[]): void
}
```

is the same as

```
type AzureTransport = (...args: any[]) => void;
```

You don't need the curly brackets.